# My tasks / my documents are missing on My Site

Tags: 2013, search, site-collection, mysite, my-content

It seems like I'm missing my tasks / my documents on my personal My Site. I've been investigating this problem for some time now and it seems like each user do not get their own site collection either. Shouldn't they get their own site collection?

I've created Work Management Service with a user that have all right in user profile service + and started the service + run several search crawls but the content library's do not get created. All I have on Site contents are:

- form templates
- organization logos
- style library
- user photos

Answer (score 1):

The libraries that you are listing are part of the My Site Host, not the users personal site. Each user has to create a personal site in order for the WMS to have the necessary lists for tasks. (The Social Features need a personal site as well for the newsfeed.) Click on "About Me" and you should be prompted to create your personal site. By default these are created under the "personal" managed path and, depending on how you configured the User Profile Service, will be named based on their username (or domain_username). This is where you will see the Tasks page.

Remember too that the WMS will only consolidate tasks from SharePoint sites (and Project Server sites) that are in Web Applications that are part of the WMS Proxy Group (and Associated Exchange 2013 Servers).